# Linear molecule that is liquid at room temp. and pressure?

Tags: molecules

I am trying to find a linear molecule that is a liquid at room temperature and pressure.

Do you know of any?

By linear I mean that all the bonds are co-linear (ie. simple alkane carbon chains don't count). Non hazardous materials are preferable.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dicyanoacetylene

Comment: [Bromine, B.P. 58.8 °C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bromine)

Comment: [Dichloroacetylene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichloroacetylene) is an oily pyrophoric liquid BP 33 °C - explodes.

Comment: Also dibromoacetylene and, who knows, maybe even a hundred others - don't ask such open-ended questions!

Comment: @Mithoron, Hmm may I ask why? I am actually trying to figure out a suitable molecule for a Raman spectroscopy experiment in my lab and the answers to this question helped me out a lot (and it would've helped me if someone had asked it in the past). Should I close it? Does it go against the rules?

Comment: Well, I put a "too broad" close vote, it's up to others if they agree. This is a bit of a grey area, but unfortunately questions "are they any" tend to lead to a list of examples, which isn't a favourable outcome.

Comment: Well, that is a typical example of an xy problem: You are asking about y without the context of x. If you had described the purpose you want it for, and possibly given some tighter criteria of what you are looking for, this would be a less broad question, be of more use for further guests, possibly have a wider audience, and will most likely have been perceived better. I generally agree with Mithoron about it being too broad.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン alright, I don't see the harm of having this question up nonetheless... I already found what I wanted. Should I delete it? Am I harming the stack exchange by keeping it up?

Comment: You cannot delete it; and I never even implied that this was the way forward. I would encourage you to improve the question by [edit]ing it. You might be surprised to find even more answers eventually, and that would be a great service to future users of this site, just liked you would have found it helpful if someone had asked a question similar to this.

Comment: @Gyromagnetic: Does 2-butyne count? Its melting point is $\pu{-32 ^\circ C}$ and boiling point is $\pu{27 ^\circ C}$.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne Nah, he wants all atoms in line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically liquid, but close to the boiling point and a bit nasty to work with, is [carbon disulfide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_disulfide).  It melts at about -112°C and boils at +46°C.